# Find a vector such that $L(x)=<x,v>.$

Tags: linear-algebra

$<.,.>$ is an inner product on U

If $e_1,e_2,e_3$ is a basis for $U$, let

$e_1=<e_{j},e_j> =2$ such that $j=1,2,3$ and that

$<e_1,e_2>=1$

$<e_1,e_3>=1$

$<e_2,e_3>=1$

Suppose $L(ae_1+be_2+ce_3)=a+b+c.$ Find a vector such that $L(x)=<x,v>.$

### My attempt

I can see that $L(e_j)=1$

I think that the first step is to let $v=pe_1+qe_2+re_3\subset U$ and now we get $v=pe_1+qe_2+re_3=1$. Am I right? What should i do next?

Comment: What do you mean by $e_1=\langle e_j,e_j\rangle$? One is a vector, the other a number.

Comment: $<e_j,e_j>$ such that $<.,.>$ is an inner product on U. both vectors I think. The inner product of <ej,ej> = 2 = $e_1$

Comment: Let $v=\sum_k v_k e_k$, then you have $L(e_1) = L(e_2) = L(e_3) = 1$, this gives three equations in the unknowns $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data you've given, the inner product is represented by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 &2 \end{bmatrix}$$ so if $x^T=\begin{bmatrix} A & B & C\end{bmatrix}$ (treated as unknown), we have $$\begin{bmatrix} A & B & C\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 &2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\\c \end{bmatrix}=a+b+c.$$ This is equivalent to the system (explain why!) $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 &2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ whose solution is $$ \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1/4 \\ 1/4 \\ 1/4 \end{bmatrix}$$